# Kendo grid loosing selected row

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI for my grid everything works find with that. I can select one or many rows using scroll and shift. The problem is that if I select row 3 and then some event refresh the grid and after that I want to select row 4 too Kendo is selecting all the above rows, in this case from row 1-4.

So my question is how can I solve this issue?

**Desired result in the demo: Select Germany, refresh grid, then select until Belgium. The demo is going to select from row 1 to Belgium.**

Here is a [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UcojU)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>

      $(function () {

        var selectedOrders = [];
        var idField = "OrderID";
                $('#refresh').click(() => {
            $("#grid").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
        })
        
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "OrderID",
                fields: {
                  OrderID: { type: "number" },
                  Freight: { type: "number" },
                  ShipName: { type: "string" },
                  OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                  ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                }
              }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
          },
          height: 400,
          selectable: "multiple",
          pageable: {
            buttonCount: 5
          },
          sortable: true,
          filterable: true,
          navigatable: true,
          columns: [
            {
              field: "ShipCountry",
              title: "Ship Country",
              width: 300
            },
            {
              field: "Freight",
              width: 300
            },
            {
              field: "OrderDate",
              title: "Order Date",
              format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
            }
          ],
          change: function (e, args) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var items = grid.items();
            items.each(function (idx, row) {
              var idValue = grid.dataItem(row).get(idField);
              if (row.className.indexOf("k-state-selected") >= 0) {
                selectedOrders[idValue] = true;
              } else if (selectedOrders[idValue]) {
                delete selectedOrders[idValue];
              }
            });
          },
          dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var items = grid.items();
            var itemsToSelect = [];
            items.each(function (idx, row) {
              var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
              if (selectedOrders[dataItem[idField]]) {
                itemsToSelect.push(row);
              }
            });

            e.sender.select(itemsToSelect);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that kendo is selecting all rows before your `change` event, that is causing the problem inside your event.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is so similar to the problem I had which I wrote about here, [Kendo Grid Persist Row Example](https://jpllosa.blogspot.com/2021/10/kendo-grid-persist-row-selection-example.html). In the example I wrote, I used `persistSelection` which is recommended.

This behaviour is happening because after the refresh event the grid no longer knows which row was focused previously. So on `dataBound`, we need to set that focus back. Here's a snippet that might help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        var selectedOrders = [];
        var idField = "OrderID";
        $('#refresh').click(() => {
            $("#grid").getKendoGrid().dataSource.read();
        });
        
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
          dataSource: {
            type: "odata",
            transport: {
              read: "http://demos.kendoui.com/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
            },
            schema: {
              model: {
                id: "OrderID",
                fields: {
                  OrderID: { type: "number" },
                  Freight: { type: "number" },
                  ShipName: { type: "string" },
                  OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                  ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                }
              }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            serverSorting: true
          },
          height: 400,
          selectable: "multiple",
          pageable: {
            buttonCount: 5
          },
          sortable: true,
          filterable: true,
          navigatable: true,
          columns: [
            {
              field: "ShipCountry",
              title: "Ship Country",
              width: 300
            },
            {
              field: "Freight",
              width: 300
            },
            {
              field: "OrderDate",
              title: "Order Date",
              format: "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"
            }
          ],
          change: function (e, args) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var items = grid.items();
            items.each(function (idx, row) {
              var idValue = grid.dataItem(row).get(idField);
              if (row.className.indexOf("k-state-selected") >= 0) {
                selectedOrders[idValue] = true;
              } else if (selectedOrders[idValue]) {
                delete selectedOrders[idValue];
              }
            });
          },
          dataBound: function (e) {
            var grid = e.sender;
            var items = grid.items();
            var itemsToSelect = [];
            items.each(function (idx, row) {
              var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
              if (selectedOrders[dataItem[idField]]) {
                itemsToSelect.push(row);
              }
            });
            
            if (itemsToSelect.length > 0) {
              var lastRow = itemsToSelect[itemsToSelect.length - 1];
              grid.selectable._lastActive = lastRow;
              grid.current($(lastRow).find("td:first"));
            }

            e.sender.select(itemsToSelect);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get and persist selected row on a specific page after edit or paging  in change and databound events like this:

```
Grid_OnRowSelect = function (e) {                
    this.currentPageNum = grid.dataSource.page();
    //Save index of selected row      
    this.selectedIndex = grid.select().index();       
}

.Events(e => e.DataBound(
    @<text>
        function(e)
        {
            //جهت نمایش صحیح پیجینگ
            var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.pager.resize();          

            //در صورت تغییر صفحه، سطر را انتخاب نکند
            if(this.currentPageNum == grid.dataSource.page())
            {
                //انتخاب مجدد سطر انتخاب شده قبل از ویرایش
                var row = grid.table.find("tr:eq(" + this.selectedIndex + ")");
                grid.select(row);
            }
        }
    </text>)
 )
```

in your case you can set rows in a list and use in databound